# Theorem about uniqueness of solution

Tags: articles, mathematics

I want to write down such a theorem.

**Theorem**. Strong existence and pathwise uniqueness hold for Equation (8). A unique solution is a continuous Markov process.

I have a question concerning the usage of an article. Should I write "A unique solution" or "The unique solution"?

As a non-native speaker of English, I have problems understanding how
to use the phrase "a unique solution" solution correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Examples from maths

*the* is specific and *a* is general.

For example, we say "the free Abelian group on two generators" (because there is only one up to isomorphism) and "a free Abelian group" (because there are many).

"The identity matrix" (if it's clear from context what dimension we mean, so there's only one) vs "a non-singular matrix", or equivalently "an invertible matrix"

### "The" is used when we're referring to a particular thing.

> Theorem. Strong existence and pathwise uniqueness hold for Equation (8). The unique solution is a continuous Markov process.

Here *the* is used because *the* is definite. We use *the* when we are referring to a particular thing, not a general thing.

### "A" is used when we're referring to any thing that matches the discription

Theorem. Strong existence holds for Equation (8). The equation has a pathwise unique solution which is a continuous Markov process.

We have to use "a" here because the adjectival "pathwise unique" doesn't alter the fact that we need "a" in "The equation has a solution". We would also say (in maths contexts) "There exists a solution" and even "There exists a unique solution". We use "a" before we have made the solution definite, so if you haven't yet claimed uniqueness you would write

> A solution to this equation is given by M(t)=..... The solution is pathwise unique since....

But if you claim uniqueness first, you would write

> This equation has a pathwise unique solution. The solution is given by M(t)=....

### Why does "a unique solution" appear more often than "the unique solution"?

The phrase "a unique solution" is very common, because we like to claim that something has a unique solution before we introduce it. Once we've introduced it, "this solution" is a more common way of referring to it than "the unique solution":

> Equation (*) has a unique solution. The solution is determined by the Lipschitz condition on the diffusion....

but we would likely say

> Equation (**) has a unique solution. This solution of course determines a continuous .....

There's a small window when we would refer to the solution as "the unique solution" - after we'd said there was only one, but before we'd defined it, after which we would perhaps be more inclined to call it this solution or refer to it as M(t) or similar.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. When we write 'a unique solution' we also refer to a particular thing, yet we use 'a', because we have not introduced this solution before, and adjective 'unique' does not play a special role. Is that right?

Comment: @Sinusx Correct - the adjective cannot alter the English structure of _that_ sentence, but will alter whether we use "a" afterwards. We can't say "a unique solution" more than once unless we change which equation we're talking about: "This has a unique solution. A solution is given by M(t)=..." feels wrong. It should be "This has a unique solution. The solution is given by M(t)=...".

Answer (score 1):

Use 'the'.

'A' implies there is more than one. 'Unique' and 'the' imply there is exactly one.

Comment: Why 'the' is appropriate in this context? Ngram shows, that 'a unique solution' is more common. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+unique+solution+%2C+the+unique+solution&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20unique%20solution%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20unique%20solution%3B%2Cc0